# Shorten delay when hovering over auto-hide panel / toolbars in Visual Studio '08

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

I've disabled the animation for auto-hide panels or toolbars, but i would like to shorten the delay when hovering over them. Somebody any idea how i can do that. I did not find an option in the environment settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tools` then `Options` then `Environment` then `General` has a check box for `Animate environment tools`.  Below that is a slider that allows you to adjust the speed.  - is slower, + is faster.  Or just turn it off altogether.

I see now that you're looking to shorten the delay before the panel pops up.  I don't see where that's configurable.

Comment: It appears this has been (re)moved in Visual Studio 2010. Any idea where I can find it here?